# How to avoid outputting a auto generated directory when downloading tensorflow hub module

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Code:

```
import os 

path = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3" + "?tf-hub-format=compressed"

os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = '/use_multilingual/20220406235959/'

hub.load(path)
```

When I do run this, it automatically appends some hash directory at the end:

```
/use_multilingual/20220406235959/328a8dfead197f0fe7268e59acba163b3a015b15
```

Is it possible for me to download the model without the hash included?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude or remove the hash sub-directory. The hash corresponds to the model name of the model being cached. Since  TFHUB_CACHE_DIR is used for all model downloads by a given process, the sub-directory is used in order to avoid the collisions.